# Uppercase usernames in Kerberos principals upon SSH login with password entry

Tags: ssh, kerberos

We've been having trouble with users logging in to our Linux machines and the username part of their Kerberos principal being in uppercase. This is a disaster for the security policies on our Hadoop cluster which expects lowercase usernames.

Background is that we have CentOS 7.3 machines which are contacting a Windows AD.

I've found the circumstances under which this happens. I ssh into one of the Linux machines. I'm not using my SSH key so I have to enter my password. When I do this I get the username of the Kerberos principal in uppercase:

```
[root@machine1 ~]# ssh jasbre@machine2
jasbre@machine2's password:
Last login: Mon Sep 18 12:06:13 2017 from machine1
[jasbre@machine ~]$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1379946670
Default principal: JASBRE@XXX.YYY.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
09/18/2017 12:13:21  09/18/2017 22:13:21  krbtgt/XXX.YYY.COM@XXX.YYY.COM
        renew until 09/25/2017 12:13:21
```

Now I login with my SSH key and don't have a Kerberos ticket when I log in (since I haven't entered a password). I then do a kinit and I get the lowercase username in the principal:

```
[jasbre@machine2 ~]$ kinit
Password for jasbre@XXX.YYY.COM:
[jasbre@machine2 ~]$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1379946670
Default principal: jasbre@XXX.YYY.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
09/18/2017 12:14:13  09/18/2017 22:14:13  krbtgt/XXX.YYY.COM@XXX.YYY.COM
        renew until 09/25/2017 12:14:07
```

What's going on here? I assume it is just something that I'm getting back from the domain controller. Can I somewhere steer this with my sssd.conf file on the Linux machine? I'm already have `case_sensitive = false` in sssd.conf.